# Compare value to another spreadsheet using array loop and write new values

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

Hello all I'm having trouble implementing array loops in my project... Here is what I want to do.

I have a spreadsheet called "Red Book" this sheet gets updated regularly once the staff have updated it I have a column where they can select to submit the data they've just entered on that specific row (editing this column calls an onEdit function).

The data will then be written to another spreadsheet (different file) called "Raw Data"

For each submit I have a unique identifier.  I need the onEdit code to do the following...

1. Iterate through the column A to find the unique identifier
2. Once found update the data in columns 1 through 5

Below is the script I have so far:

```
function TransferToAppData(e) {
  var destFile = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
  var destSheet = destFile.getSheetByName("Raw App Data");
  var ss = e.source;
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var uniConstRng = s.getRange("A1");
  var uniqueConstVal = uniConstRng.getValue();
  var NextOpenRow = destSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
  var ActiveRow = e.range.getRow();
  Logger.log(ActiveRow);
  var uniqueVal = s.getRange(ActiveRow,1).getValue();
  var add = s.getRange(ActiveRow,2).getValue();
  var name = s.getRange(ActiveRow,3).getValue();
  var dt = s.getRange(ActiveRow,5).getValue()
  if (uniqueVal == "") {
    s.getRange(ActiveRow,1).setValue(uniqueVal + 1);
    uniConstRng.setValue(uniqueVal + 1);
    var transferVals = s.getRange(ActiveRow,1,1,5).getValues();
      Logger.log(transferVals);
    destSheet.getRange(NextOpenRow,1,1,5).setValues(transferVals);
    destSheet.getRange(NextOpenRow, 6).setValue("Applicant");
  }
  else {
    var destLastRow = destSheet.getLastRow();
    var destDataRng = destSheet.getRange(2,1,destLastRow,5)
    var destValues = destDataRng.getValues();
    var sourceValues = s.getRange(ActiveRow,1,1,5).getValues();
    for( var i = 0; i < destValues.length; ++i){
      if (destValues([i][0])==uniqueVal) {
        for(n=0;n<destValues[0].length;++n){
          ///I"m stuck!!!

        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see I have the first array loop going, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do a second loop that iterates only on the row where the unique value is found and write the source data to **ONLY to row where the unique value was found not the whole sheet**.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could reduce this down to a succinct question that addresses exactly the part of your code you're having a problem with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out...

Below is the code and here is how it works...

When values in certain columns are edited this code is fired.

1--It finds the unique identifier located in the row which was edited.

2--Compares that identifier with a column of unique identifiers in another spreadsheet.

3--When a match is found it writes the change to the new spreadsheet and exits the loop

```
function TransferToAppData(e) {
  var destFile = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1V3R2RnpA8yXmz_JDZSkBsK9tGR2LjHZp52p5I1CuQvw');
  var destSheet = destFile.getSheetByName("Raw App Data");
  var ss = e.source;
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var uniqueConstRng = s.getRange("A1");
  var uniqueConstVal = uniqueConstRng.getValue();
  var NextOpenRow = destSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
  var ActiveRow = e.range.getRow();
  var uniqueVal = s.getRange(ActiveRow,1).getValue();
  if (s.getRange(ActiveRow,2).getValue() == "" || s.getRange(ActiveRow,3).getValue()=="" || s.getRange(ActiveRow,4).getValue()=="" || s.getRange(ActiveRow,5).getValue()=="") {
    s.getRange(ActiveRow,13).clearContent();
    Browser.msgBox("Address, Name, Date Entered & Rent are required fields!");
  } else{
    if (uniqueVal == "") {
      s.getRange(ActiveRow,1).setValue(uniqueConstVal + 1);
      uniqueConstRng.setValue(uniqueConstVal + 1);
      var transferVals = s.getSheetValues(ActiveRow,1,1,5);
      destSheet.getRange(NextOpenRow,1,1,5).setValues(transferVals);
      destSheet.getRange(NextOpenRow, 6).setValue("Applicant");
    }
    else {
      var destLastRow = destSheet.getLastRow();
      var destValues = destSheet.getSheetValues(2,1,destLastRow,5);
      var sourceValues = s.getSheetValues(ActiveRow,1,1,5);
      for(var i = 0; i < destValues.length; ++i){
        if (destValues[i][0]===uniqueVal) {
          destSheet.getRange(i+2,1,1,5).setValues(sourceValues);
          break;
          }
        }
      }
     s.sort(1,false);
     destSheet.sort(1,false);
   }
  }
```